# android how to get the maximum size of NDEF message payload from reading a NFC tag

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

I'm developing an android application to write to a specific memory location of a nfc tag.
And I need to get the maximum size of NDEF message payload from reading an NFC tag, so that I can define memory location within that range.

I know that it is able to get the whole ndef memory size by the code below:

Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
int size = ndef.getMaxSize();

Are there any approach to get the maximum payload size?

Any help would be much appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the max payload size allowed by the spec is 2^32-1

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefRecord.html

you can get the variable-length payload and its size with [getPayload](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefRecord.html#getPayload%28%29)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It is helpful! I just found out that for plaintext payload content, actual payload is started from 8th byte of total tag memory, and for URL payload content, it will start from 6th byte. So I used the ndef.getMaxSize() minus those bytes accordingly to get the maximum payload size.

Comment: this is not quite right! the length of the 'header' data in the NDEFmessage is variable. specifically, if the payload is > than 255 bytes then the sr bit is no set and the length field becomes 4 bytes long. there is also something similar that happens with the 'il' bit being set.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you correctly, you want to know the maximum amount of data you can send in a single NDEF record in an NDEF message.

The answer depends upon which format of NDEF record you are using. I'm using the external record type which has a payload of just a bunch of bytes at the end. As far as I can tell, there is no simple way to get this as it will depend on your individual domain/type field lengths, so I actually create an 'empty' record (in actual fact there is some data in it in order to get the longer length field format) and then subtract its length from the maximum.

The maximum overall NDEF message length is specified by the compatibility container, read from the tag or device on first contact, and this varies from tag to tag. Android lets us get that with `ndefTag.getMaxSize();` (where `ndefTag` is the tag you got from the intent)

Here is the approach I am using (I have allowed for different send and receive lengths):

```
//here we make some sample transmissions that we convert to work out the max length of data we can send
int test_payload_len = 300; //need to make this >255 to ensure the longer length field format is used
NdefMessage testDeviceNdef = new NdefMessage(NdefRecord.createExternal(CommandConsts.deviceDomain, CommandConsts.deviceType, test_data)); //the domain and type strings are defined elsewhere
NdefMessage testTerminalNdef = new NdefMessage(NdefRecord.createExternal(CommandConsts.terminalDomain, CommandConsts.terminalType, test_data));

maxNdefDeviceSendLength = ndefTag.getMaxSize() - (testDeviceNdef.getByteArrayLength() - test_payload_len); 
maxNdefTerminalSendLength = ndefTag.getMaxSize() - (testTerminalNdef.getByteArrayLength() - test_payload_len)
```